# How to defined MPI_Type_struct where a generic pointer is involved in the struct

Tags: c, mpi

Consider the following struct

```
    typedef struct{
       void *data;
       int len;
    }item_t;
```

It allows me to pass **item_t** to a function called **map_functions(item_t dt , item_t (*f_ptr)(item_t) )** 
that accepts item_t and function pointer.

**map_functions()** will then call the function passed as argument by passing **item_t** to it.
Having in mind that there are different functions that will call **map_functions()** each with diffirent content of **item_t** and pass the corresponding function they want to call.

All this thing works well for me pretty fine.

Now, I want to do this same thing using MPI. 
The first thing that comes to my mind is:

how can I define a user defined MPI_Datatype (specifically MPI_Type_struct) 
where a generic pointer such as **void* data** is involved in the struct? i.e to convert the above struct to a user defined MPI Datatype equivalent.

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass pointers between processes, they do not share memory.

You have to pass real information, or nothing. Pointers are relative only to the process.